# Definition of constant group scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I don't understand the definition of a constant group scheme given here.

[image]

What is the "direct sum of copies of $S$?"  Is this meant to be disjoint union?

Comment: Where is this from? We can give better help if we know what book or paper contains this definition. Your guess is has a good chance of being correct, if at least because both direct sum and disjoint union are coproducts.

Comment: This is from "Abelian Varieties" by Gerard van der Geer and Ben Moonen

Comment: You're right (essentially; this definition could be more clear). Example of the constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ over the field $k$: take $\text{Spec}(k\oplus k)$ label the first copy 0 and the second 1, then the action map is the usual group multiplication. You can convert to the functor point of view as they mention above.